# DOORS DXL Export to .xlsx unreadable...except in Word

Tags: excel, export, ibm-doors

I have a DOORS DXL script that (used to) export data to an Excel worksheet.  It uses the filename specified/chosen through a GUI and tacks ".xlsx" on the end.

Well, the file is created and written to by the application.  You cannot, however, open it with Excel, as the application complains
that "Excel cannot open the file 'Output.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is invalid."  You *can* open it with Word 2016
and the text is totally readable.  (??!!!)

This script was last used/modified in 2011.  I believe the DOORS version was 9.1 on that project.  Is that a contributing factor?  (Using DOORS 9.6 on current project)

Anyone have any idea what debug steps I should take?

Thanks,

T Wilk

Comment: Can you post the code in question?

Comment: Tried, but code exceeds limits by over 10,600 characters!  Is there some place to email it?

Comment: I'm specifically interested in the sections that create your output file. What happens if you change the code to add '.xls' instead?

Answer (score 1):

I tried exporting to .xls, and it worked, sort of...  I had other problems to work through, so maybe if I went back and tried it again, now that those are solved, it would be fine.

Found out some interesting stuff today.  I changed the 'file create' extension to .tsv, made my delimiter "\t", and the export worked beautifully.  And .tsv files can easily be saved as .xlsx.  Don't know what changed between DXL and Excel since the last time I used them together, but the straight export to .xlsx is not an option.

I also learned, since the last time I did this sort of thing, i.e., DOORS to Excel, that API's have been created so that you don't have to bother with setting up the 
export in your code.  Someone pointed me to some Mike Sunderland code (Galactic Solutions).  I'm going to pick that apart tomorrow.

Got a lot to do, and I'm having  fun!

Thanks for the time and interest.
Tara